# Bootstrap 3 - How to make the glyphicon and text_field_tag align together?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, twitter-bootstrap

Here is our Rails 4 login page looks like:

[image]

The height of the `glyphicon` and `text_field_tag` are not the same. Here is the html.erb code(please ignore the tr):

```
       <div class="form-group">
        <div class="input-group"> 
            <span class="input-group-addon">
                <i class="glyphicon glyphicon-user"></i>
                    </span><%= text_field_tag :login, '' %></p></td>
                        </div>
                    </div>

                <div class="form-group">
                        <div class="input-group">
                            <span class="input-group-addon">
                                <i class="glyphicon glyphicon-lock"></i>
                                    </span> <%= password_field_tag :password, ''%>
                        </div>
                    </div>
```

The `text_field_tag` only has a size option which regulate the number of chars in display. Is there a way to increase the height of the tag so it would match that of the glyphicon? If needed,  inline css or internal css are fine for this page.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to add the class `form-control` to the input fields. That's how bootstrap is designed.

Comment: `<%= text_field_tag :login, '', :class => "form-control" %>` works. Thanks.

Comment: <div style="margin-bottom: 25px" class="input-group">
          <span class="input-group-addon"><i class="glyphicon glyphicon-lock"></i></span>
          <input id="i2" type="password" placeholder="Password" required="" name="i2" class="form-control">
        </div> did not work for me

Comment: Try to change your `span` into a `div`. Otherwise take a look at http://getbootstrap.com/css/#forms

Comment: @redelschaap I'm having this issue only with the password glyphicon types. I have replace <i/> with <span/> with no success.

Answer (score 1):

There are fragments of a table structure in the html 'tr' 'td', and a '/p'--maybe they're artifacts of an earlier implementation? They need to be removed.

Here's a one button example.

```
<%= form_for (outer loop)
 <div class="input-group">
     <%= text_field_tag :login, placeholder: "Enter user", :class => "form-control" %>
      <span class="input-group-btn">
        <%= button_tag  name: nil, class: "btn btn-default", type: "submit" do %>
         <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-user" aria-hidden="true"></span>
        <% end %>
     </span>
    </div> <!-- "input-group" --> 

<% end %> <!-- form_for -->
```

I think this will solve the display alignment issue.